# Find initial ranks

Tags: sorting, binary-trees

Assume there is an array $A$ of $n$ elements. $A$ contains every number from $1$ to $n$. We are given an array $B$ of $n$ elements. If we move each element $A[i]$ left by $B[i]$ places starting from $i = 0$ until $n-1$, in the end array $A$ will be sorted in increasing order, i.e. it will be $A = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]$. Given array $B$, find the initial value of array $A$.

For example, if $B = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1]$, $A$ will be $[3, 2, 1, 5, 4]$: We move $A[1]$ left by $1$, then $A[2]$ left by $2$, then $A[4]$ left by $1$, and $A$ becomes $[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$.
A $Θ(n^2)$ algorithm for finding $A$ is trivial. I know that there is an $Θ(n \log n)$ algorithm using segment trees, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can perform arithmetic in $\Theta(1)$ time, you can solve the problem in linear time.

First of all, we observe that if we move an element $k$ positions to the left, then the $k$ previous elements get moved one space to the right. Therefore, if we keep the tally of how many places an element moved, we have a naive but workable solution.

We initialize an array $C$ of size $n$, where each cell is set to $0$. Then, for all $1 \le i \le n$, we set $C[i]$ to $C[i] - B[i]$ and increment $C[i-1], C[i-2], ..., C[i-B[i]+1]$ by $1$. At the end of this loop, we simply determine $A[i] = i + C[i]$ for all $i$.

However, this solution requires $\Theta(n^2)$ operations. We may obtain a more efficient algorithm by observing that all our update operations only involve consecutive cells of the array.

We initialize to all zeroes another array $D$ of size $n$. Rather than updating $C$ as described above, for all $1 \le i \le n$ we do the following assignments:

> $D[i] \leftarrow D[i] - D[B[i]]$
>
> $D[i+1] \leftarrow D[i+1] + D[B[i]]$
>
> $D[i-B[i]] \leftarrow D[i-B[i]] + 1$
>
> $D[i] \leftarrow D[i] - 1$

Imagine that we had also updated $C$ as in the first algorithm. Then, after all the operations on $D$ it would hold that for all $k$:

$$
C[k] = \sum_{i = 1}^k D[i]
$$

By the above invariant, we may just leave $C$ to zero until the end of the loop. Then we set :

> $C[1] \leftarrow D[1]$

and for all $i>1$:

> $C[i] \leftarrow C[i-1] + D[i]$

And finally for all $i$:

> $A[i] = i + C[i]$

The main loop performs a constant number of additions for each element of the array and the rest of the algorithm is obviously $O(n)$, the overall complexity is therefore $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: The first $\Theta(n^2)$ algorithm is straightforward, and I came to it. I know that the best time for this algorithm is $\Theta(nlogn)$, and therefore most likely your solution is wrong. Let's try to find your error. Can you say what are you trying to hold in $D$? You wrote $D[i] = \sum_{i = 1}^n C[i]$. Can you correct this? The left side is dependent on $i$ but the right side is not.

Comment: @DavitSargsyan, it's a minor typo, I fixed it. I double checked and I stand by my solution. Community, any comments?

Answer (score -1):

Here's an $\theta(nlogn)$ solution using segment trees.

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-ways-to-solve-this-spoj-problem-SPOJ-com-Problem-ORDERS#